# How to store captured image to local storage of webos signage with sdk V1.0?

Tags: javascript, html, webos

I want to store captured image to the local storage of webos signage (TV or emulator). I have got screenshot in Base64 format. I am able to display the screenshot when I finished with taking it. But I am not able to store it.
(LG webos signage)

Comment: Found any solution till now? please let me know.